# Bootstrap form-inline not working, how can I prevent them from stacking?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar, bootstrap-5

I have a very basic test navbar, with a search input box and respective search button. I'm using **Bootstrap** class `form-inline`, yet the search button is going below the search input, altho there is plenty of space.
You can check the codepen [here](https://codepen.io/TiagoRibeiro94/pen/abpoago) so you can test it. Either way the html code is this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Nav</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>


<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-warning">
        <a href="#none" class="navbar-brand">MarcaX</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#expand">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="expand">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a href="#link1" class="nav-item nav-link">Link1</a>
                <a href="#link2" class="nav-item nav-link">Link2</a>
                <a href="#link3" class="nav-item nav-link">Link3</a>
            </div>
            <form class="form-inline ms-auto">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-light my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is something supposed to work without taking the button outside the form tag, and supposedly without any css.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are calling bootstrap v5, and `.form-inline` is dropped since v5 : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/#forms-2

You should use `.row` and `.col` to build your form layout

```
<form class="row ms-auto">
  <div class="col">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search">                
  </div>
  <div class="col-auto">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-light my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

You can find everything here : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/layout/